# Other ways to get some space between a pair of side by side Divs and have them line up when they are under one another?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

After I wrote what is below, it came to me that I could add right and bottom margins to the left divs / first set of divs instead of on the right ones (which is what I tried previously), which achieves what I want. However, I feel like it's cheating or not the right or best way to do this. So, let me know what other ways this can be done.

O.k. Here is the problem:

I have the following code. I know there are many ways to do this, but I prefer to stick to something that doesn't require too much code and most importantly, can be memorized so that I can easily do it again in the future without referring to something:

(As I said above, this is the code that works how I want it to because I added right and bottom margins.)

```
<div style="float:left;width:300px;text-align:center;margin-right:20px;margin-bottom:20px">
<div style="background-color:red">Hello Hi. One Two</div>
<div style="background-color:green">Hello Hi. One Two</div>
</div>

<div style="float:left;width:300px;text-align:center;">
<div style="background-color:aqua">Hello Hi. One Two</div>
<div style="background-color:pink">Hello Hi. One Two</div>
</div>
```

If you resize your screen horizontally to a smaller size (thus mimicking the size of a phone), the two items on the right fall directly underneath the set on the left, which is what I want.

However, in a larger screen, as on a computer, I would like to add some spacing between the divs on the left and the divs on the right. This is the tricky part though (well at least for me). After that space has been added, I want that when the screen is resized to a smaller size, that the divs line up when they are under one another. The best I am able to do is something like this when the screen is resized:

```
_____
   ______
```

The first line represents the firs set of divs and the second line represents the second set. I have to keep making my screen smaller to get the second set of divs to keep moving to the left to then line up with the first set.

So, this is what I want when the screen is resized:

```
______ 

______
```

So, that's the first set of divs, a line break or whatever produces a space between the two divs and which would be the same thing that produces a space when they are side by side, and the second set of divs that were on the right.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `@media` queries for this, and reset the `margin` when it is smaller screen.

```css
body > div {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body > div {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

**Fiddle: http://output.jsbin.com/biyidibage/1**

Comment: This feels almost like the same thing I have created as it retains the right & bottom margin & then takes them & the floating effect away. Though I suppose it makes more sense as on a smaller screen, with my solution, the margins remain when they are not needed. 1) However, as I think more about this, I am confused: How is it that when the screen is smaller there is space underneath the first set of divs if you made all the margins 0? 2) With your solution, you might need to change the 300px to 400px and 600px to 800px to see this: when the screen is smaller than the width of the divs

Comment: (so, less than 300px or 400px if you changed it), the divs no longer resize to a smaller size. With my solution, they continue re-sizing. 3) And finally, if you don't mind answering, when the screen is just under 600 pixels, but more than 300px, there is about 300px of space left to the right. How can I tell the divs to take up the full screen when only one set is on a line and the screen is less than 600px? I tried adding width:100% to the @media portion of the code, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Rolo How do they even resize, if you have given a fixed `width: 300px`. Surprising!

Comment: I just looked at what I am testing and I see that I added max-width:100% to my two main divs, which I see I did not add here. So that's why they are re-sizing. Where do I add that your code? I can't seem to get anything I add to the @media area working. Also, if you can please answer my two other questions, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @Rolo Just put it on the same class above or below. `:)`

Comment: You have a typo, `@media and screen (max-width: 600px) {` .. should be `@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {` ... still sleepy :), +1

Comment: ... fixed snippet typo for you, but you have same typo in your fiddle/jsbin

Comment: LGSon: Thank you. Thank you! Now everything makes sense. I now understand why there was a space underneath the first set of divs with this code & that's because the @media part was being ignored. So, the code as is is wrong with regards to the margins. I have to specify a bottom margin in that portion also, which to me is then pretty much the same code as what I have. Also, I was able to get the width of the divs to maximize to 100% when the screen is smaller than 600px or ,if you changed the width as I suggested to test, 800px. Code I add to that area now does stuff / works. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using `inline-block`.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.first, .second {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  min-width: 300px;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 658px) {
  .first, .second {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="first">
    <div style="background-color:red">Hello Hi. One Two</div>
    <div style="background-color:green">Hello Hi. One Two</div>
  </div><div class="second">
    <div style="background-color:aqua">Hello Hi. One Two</div>
    <div style="background-color:pink">Hello Hi. One Two</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ha ha... Nice one bro... `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thank you... can't have you show off all by yourself... :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar I hope you don't mean _can't have you show off all by yourself._, as that was meant as a joke, ... or you mean something else?

Comment: I meant that only, but didn't understand the joke yet! `:(`

Comment: @PraveenKumar Then I'm sorry if I offended you. Let me know and I will delete it immediately.

Comment: Man, you said it as a joke, I didn't understand the joke or the meaning. You can **never** offend me, so please don't worry and explain the joke.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ok, wonderful, and I meant _we can't let you show off your skills alone, I have to show off mine as well_ ... :)